# In React, how should the state of a reusable List component be managed?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a simple List component to reuse within my application and which can hold different types of elements. The state of this list corresponds to an array of elements.

What I was wondering is wether the state should be kept internally inside the List component, or externally through the parent. E.g.:

**Case 1:**

```
MyComponent = React.createClass(

  getInitialState: ->
    items: [1,2,3,4,5]

  render: ->
    List items: @state.items
)
```

**Case 2:**

```
MyComponent = React.createClass(

  render: ->
    items= [1,2,3,4,5]
    List initialState: items
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state should be kept at the highest point it's needed.  So if it's just UI state and MyComponent doesn't care about the items, then List should own it.  Otherwise MyComponent should.

State is passed down, and only comes back up with callbacks.